# Can I navigate to a specific URL in Samsung Internet Browser instead of doing a Google search?

Tags: google-search, url, samsung-internet-browser

Using Samsung Internet 11.1.2.2 on Android 8.1.0.

Whenever I type an URL in the top bar, it performs a Google search with that parameter. The worst thing is that in some cases, the target URL is not in the list of the search results. Thus, I cannot go to the intended URL.

**Is there any solution for this, so I can visit the target URL in Samsung Internet Browser?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply disable the automatic searching for entered values in the address bar:

Open Settings -> Search engine and disable "Suggest websites and search terms"

[image]

Afterwards if you enter a valid DNS name like `exampleabc.com` you will get directly to the page (in this case a generated error page as the domain does not exist).

If you just enter some search terms like `holiday` a Google search will be performed.

Comment: Tested and it works

Answer (score 0):

A workaround:

1. Create a "phantom" group in WhatsApp, where you are the only member (add another person and then remove him/her).
2. Send the URL to that group.
   Or you can send the URL to any other contact, if that is not a problem for you and the other.
3. Click on the URL in WhatsApp.

It will open the browser and navigate to the URL.

Plus, you can save the bookmark now.

Comment: What does your answer uses WhatsApp? This app was not mentioned in your question, hence from my perspective your answer does not make sense to me.

Comment: @Robert - The question does not **require** use of WhatsApp, but it does not **preclude** it either.
The answer shows a method that, using WhatsApp, leads to the intended objective.
I used it and it worked.
I would not understand what do you find strange about this.